# After Windows 7 upgrade, can't connect to our Netgear AP

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

My Husband took his desktop to our computer guy to have it fixed and upgraded from XP to Windows 7. We have a wireless Netgear router. We have the USB that we used with the XP-running system. I have tried to connect and it says it detects no wireless connections. We took it back because they thought I was doing something wrong, but the connection worked at the shop. I have used the same SSID and password. I am not a computer wiz at all I just get by.

Answer (score 1):

To get wireless access from the desktop, you plug a USB device into a port on his desktop system? If so, the system may be missing the driver for that device. If the device came with a CD and you still have the CD, you may need to insert it into the CD/DVD drive and run a setup program on the CD to install the appropriate driver for the USB wireless device, if that is what you are using.

Oppen the **Device Manager** on the system with the wireless device plugged in and look under "Network Adapters". Do you see the device listed? To check, take the following steps in Windows 7:

1. Click on the Windows **Start** button in the lower, left-hand corner of the screen, then select **Control Panel**.
2. Click on **Hardware and Sound**.
3. Under **Devices and Printers**, click on **Device Manager**.
4. Double-click on **Network Adapters** in the **Device Manager**window.

You should see a wireless adapter listed. If you see something identified as "uknown device" with an exclamation mark next to it, Windows is missing the driver for the wireless device. The original CD may or may not have a driver for Windows 7 depending on how old it may be. If it doesn't have an appropriate driver you may need to go to the manufacturer's website and download a Windows 7 driver for the device. If you don't have Internet access on your husband's PC now, you may need to do that on another computer and then put the file on a USB flash drive to transfer to his system. What is the device you use on his system to get wireless access and was that taken to the shop with the system, so that the technicians there used it to obtain wireless network access?

It is somewhat confusing when you state that "I have used the same ssid and password", since I wouldn't expect you would be prompted for a [WEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy) or [WPA/WPA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access) key, i.e., a "password", unless the system found a wireless network to which it was trying to connect, yet you also state "I have tried to connect and it says it detects no wireless connections."